# QEMU-AFL: follow fork() into child

Tags: qemu, fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop

I've been scouring the AFL++ and QEMU docs for a while and I can't seem to find an answer to this question: can you instruct QEMU-AFL (AFL++'s fork of QEMU, used when running `afl-fuzz -Q`) to follow forks created in the process currently being fuzzed?

A very simple example would be a `parent` binary and a `child` binary (see code below). The `parent` binary "fork + exec"s the `child` binary, and the child binary reads a character from `stdin` and crashes if it's equal to `'c'`. The crash is propagated to the `parent` binary.

When I run this with `afl-fuzz -i in/ -o out/ -Q -- ./parent`, I get:

```
last new find : none yet (odd, check syntax!)
```

which leads me to believe that AFL++ is not actually tracking coverage in the child process. Since [it seems possible to do this with instrumented binaries](https://groups.google.com/g/afl-users/c/ANsA4BZvr9Y/m/1hnRLHphAQAJ), I assume the limitation is not in AFL++, but in QEMU-AFL. Is there a way to instruct QEMU-AFL (or QEMU for that matter) to follow forks?

---

Code for `parent.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello from the parent!\n");

    pid_t new_pid = fork();

    if (new_pid == 0) {
        execve("./child", argv, NULL);
        return 0;
    }

    // Wait for child to finish.
    int child_retcode = 0;
    while (wait(&child_retcode) > 0);

    return child_retcode;
}
```

Code for `child.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello from the child!\n");

    char c1 = getchar();
    char c2 = getchar();
    if (c1 == 'c') {
        printf("Oh no, we're crashing!\n");
        abort();
    }

    return 0;
}
```